# Prove that exist $g$ such that $g(x) = f(x) + \alpha\int_0^1g(y)\sin[\cos(x-y)] \mathrm dy$ for all $x\in [0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $\alpha$ be a real constant and $f\in C[0,1]$. Prove that there exist $g\in C[0,1]$ such that
       $$g(x) = f(x) + \alpha\int_0^1g(y)\sin[\cos(x-y)] \; \mathrm dy , \quad \forall x\in[0,1].$$
I have absolutely no idea how even to start.
Can anybody help me ?

Comment: One idea (I did not try myself): rewrite the right hand side as an operator $T$ from $C[0,1]$ to $C[0,1]$ in $g$ and try to solve the fixed point problem $g=Tg$.

Comment: Are there any more restrictions to $\alpha$?

Comment: Fredholm alternative? The kernel is smooth, so the operator $T$ would be compact, I think..